# MAUI Shell remove OverScroll from the sides

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui, .net-maui

I've bein workeing on my app. It's useing `SwipeView` and 9 times out of 10, when I want to swipe the item to remove it - I get this (as I called it) ScrollPreview (I have no idea how it's actually called). The source of this blue thing seems to come from `Shell` (`AppShell`).

[image: Blue thing example]

Is there any way to remove it?

Edit:
On further investigartion it seems to be connected to `ShellContent`. The `OverScroll` (the name pointed out by Gerald Versluis in the comments) does not appear if underlying structure if it is not based on `ShellContent`.

Comment: The correct term (for Android) is overscroll :) I tried to figure out how to disable it, but couldn't find it just yet... Maybe the term will help you figure out a bit more at least :D

Comment: Make a new project on Maui (the overscroll already exist by default in latest version where AppShell exists by default). <Shell
    x:Class="Overscroll.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Overscroll"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled">

  <ShellContent
        Title="Hello, World!"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
        Route="MainPage" />

</Shell>

Answer (score -1):

Sveiki! If you don't mind disabling the scroll glow effect in your whole application adding this style in `res/values/styles.xml` would be the easiest fix:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:overScrollMode">never</item>
</style>
```

Or you can just [opt out in your layouts file](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scroll#overscroll-opt-out-layout-file) for a single layout:

```
<MyCustomView android:overScrollMode="never">
...
</MyCustomView>
```